# getting data of dynamic fields created by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have to create a form consisting dynamic wizards with dynamic fields
in angularJs.

Code for this is as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in wizard.Wizardfields">  
            {{field.label}}
            <input type="{{field.type}}"  placeholder="{{field.label}}" ng-model="field.value" />
        </div> 
<input type="button" value="Next" ng-click="next(field)" />
```

Now,fields are being created but I can't figure out how to get data entered in all fields in Angular controller. Thanx for Any Help Regarding This...

**EDIT**

Now i have data of all the fields by this solution

```
<input type="{{field.type}}"  placeholder="{{field.label}}" ng-model="values[$index]" />
```

but there is no distinction of what value is of which fields.

I mean it gives array like ["abc","12"] while i want it like [name:"abc",age:"12"]...Or in any form in which data of specific field can be recognized...

Comment: `field` is out of scope for your above `ng-click="next(field)"`

Comment: but if i place button inside div it'll be repeated after every input field.is there any other solution to this just want to save form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the values into an array of values using $index:

```
<input type="{{field.type}}"  placeholder="{{field.label}}" ng-model="values[$index]" />
```

As shown in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/abaD3bDoq0TctUfcU4AW?p=preview).

Comment: thanx it worked but its giving output as   ["abc","123"]  if want it as [studentName:"abc",age:"123"].something like ng-model="values[field.fieldName:$index]"......what can be done cz its not working

Comment: Just to make sure i understood your problem, the problem is that the fields are not on the scope, so once you click 'next' - the data is gone, right? cause if you still have the data, your code is perfectly fine. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9zPVf691zPC1wrAG8pgP)